# Transmogrification Rules and Groups

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I want to build myself some nice options in the `Void Storage`, specifically regarding weapon choices, but I need some clarity on the rules/groups around `Transmogrification`.

Firstly, are your options limited to your armor skill only (`Plate`, `Mail`, `Leather`, `Cloth`), or can you use anything that you could wear?

Secondly, regarding weapons, how is it decided which designs can be applied to which weapons? Can all 2-handed weapons fit on each other, or is it like Swords on Swords only, etc, or is it more specific than that?

Also, I heard that you cannot apply the design of a `Legendary Item` to anything (which I understand for exclusivity purposes), but does the opposite apply? Can I apply a design to perhaps conceal my `Legendary Cloak`, or make it look like something that I like more?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firstly, armor types can only have the same armor types applied to them;
cloth to cloth, plate to plate etc.

For example, a warrior (who can wear any armor type) can transmogrify a piece of cloth armor, but only with another piece of cloth armor. Therefore defeating the whole point of it in their case, as they could just wear the piece of cloth.

Secondly, weapon transmogrification is restricted to which weapons share the same animations. For example, 2h axes can be transmogged to 2h maces and 2h swords, but because 2h staves and 2h polearms use a different animation, they can't. The different animation groups are as follows:

- 1h axe, mace, sword
- 2h axe, mace, sword
- 2h polearm, staff
- bow, crossbow, gun (see below)

An exception to the rule. Hunters are allowed to transmogrify with different animation types with regards to bows, crossbows and guns.

Daggers, fists, shields and wands can only be transmogrified with themselves.

Finally, as you have noted, you cannot apply a design of a Legendary Item to anything. Unfortunately the same applies the other way. The only option if you don't like your cloak is to hide it in the UI options.

A decent guide can be found [here](http://www.wowhead.com/guide=1564/how-to-transmogrify-and-what-you-can-and-cannot-do). It seems they are keeping it up-to-date as changes are made.

Comment: Worth noting that this *may* change when Warlords of Draenor is released. To my knowledge it hasn't been announced, but it's a more expansive transmog system on the alpha: http://wow.joystiq.com/2014/06/26/warlords-of-draenor-alpha-transmog-changes/